# fighting touch events on mobile devices, highjacking normal scroll

Tags: javascript, mobile, scroll, touch, touch-event

I went through the code several times and I cannot find the reason it fails on touch based devices:

```
    /**
     * Initialize touch event listener.
     *
     * @returns {Plugin}
     */
    touch: function () {
        var self = this;

        this._$body.bind('touchstart', function (event) {
            var startEvent = event.originalEvent.touches[0];

            event.preventDefault();
            self._$body.bind('touchmove', function (event) {
                var moveEvent = event.originalEvent.touches[0];
                var diff = { x: startEvent.clientX - moveEvent.clientX, y: startEvent.clientY - moveEvent.clientY };
                var nextStep;
                event.preventDefault();
                if ((diff.y <= -100 || diff.y >= 100) && Math.abs(diff.y) > Math.abs(diff.x)) {
                    nextStep = diff.y < 0 ? self._currentStep - 1 : self._currentStep + 1;
                    self.customScrollTo(nextStep);
                }
                return false;
            });

            return false;
        });

        return this;
    },
```

demo (self signed ssl, don't worry!): https://sandbox.idev.ge/roomshotel/html5_v3/

**Problem:** Scroll jumps straight to bottom when touch is activated.

**Expected result:** One touch interaction equals 1 section scrolled.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Scroll doesn't work at all for me

Comment: Normal scroll doesn't work in Chrome and touch doesn't work in mobile safari

Comment: @salivan give me some time, I'll try to figure it out. BTW, you'll quickly run out of your repo if you continue to set so many bounties))

Comment: @SamBraslavskiy well, these are tough questions, so I don't think it is fare to you guys to let them be normal point questions... I'm accumulating REP just for these cases :)

Comment: Somehow a lot of those .jpg and .svg don't load for me. Don't know if that is just me, though.

Comment: @salivan Do you want to like this when we swipe up or down then only one section should scroll right ?

Comment: @salivan I have answered it you can check. I found easiest way to handle swipe. I have used it in my project too.

Comment: @salivan Did you try my answer and checked its output. I wanted to know if its working or not.

Comment: @SSS yes, I tried, what happens with your solution is that scroll gets completely disabled, basically nothing happens.

Comment: @salivan That must be because of event.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too think the `touchmove` event's callback is being fired on every touch move. By returning `false` from that function you only cancel that single touch move event and not all following touch move events.

You cannot use a `touchend` event since you want to call `self.customScrollTo(nextStep);` as soon as the pointer has travelled 100px.

You want to prevent your `touchmove` callback from being executed after the pointer has travelled 100px, this can be done in many ways, ie.

1. Using a flag variable like `var trackPointer = true;`, check this flag
   each time `touchmove` is being triggered and set this flag to `false` when the
   pointer has travelled 100px.
2. When the pointer has travelled 100px,
   set the `startEvent` to `null` and check this variable on
   `touchmove`.
3. Unbind the `touchmove` event when the pointer has
   travelled 100px.

NB: The `touchmove` event is being bound *each time* `touchstart` is triggered on this element, these events do not overwrite each other but get stacked! So you might want to consider binding the event only once (ie. on DOM ready) or unbind the event when it's no longer necessary.

The latter is probably the easiest and could be done ie. on `touchend` (use namespaces just to be sure to not unbind the same events bound by other scripts):

```
// Unbind all touchmove.myNameSpace events on touchend.myNameSpace.
self._$body.bind('touchend.myNameSpace').function (event) {
  self._$body.unbind('touchmove.myNameSpace');
});
```

and when the pointer has travelled 100px:

```
self.customScrollTo(nextStep);
// Unbind all touchmove.myNameSpace events.
self._$body.unbind('touchmove.myNameSpace');
```

Since 'touchend' is not triggered when the pointer is outside the element (I am not sure about `touchmove`), you might also want to unbind right before binding:

```
event.preventDefault();
// Unbind all touchmove.myNameSpace events and (re)bind touchmove.myNameSpace event.
self._$body.unbind('touchmove.myNameSpace').bind('touchmove.myNameSpace', function (event) {
  var moveEvent = event.originalEvent.touches[0];
```

So you could try (I have not tested it):

```
/**
 * Initialize touch event listener.
 *
 * @returns {Plugin}
 */
touch: function () {
    var self = this;

    this._$body.bind('touchstart', function (event) {
        var startEvent = event.originalEvent.touches[0];

        event.preventDefault();
        self._$body.unbind('touchmove.myNameSpace').bind('touchmove.myNameSpace', function (event) {
            var moveEvent = event.originalEvent.touches[0];
            var diff = { x: startEvent.clientX - moveEvent.clientX, y: startEvent.clientY - moveEvent.clientY };
            var nextStep;
            event.preventDefault(); // <- Not necessary since you completely cancel the event by returning false.
            if ((diff.y <= -100 || diff.y >= 100) && Math.abs(diff.y) > Math.abs(diff.x)) {
                nextStep = diff.y < 0 ? self._currentStep - 1 : self._currentStep + 1;
                self.customScrollTo(nextStep);

                // Unbind all touchmove.myNameSpace events.
                self._$body.unbind('touchmove.myNameSpace');
            }
            return false;
        });

        return false;
    });

    // Unbind all touchmove.myNameSpace events on touchend.myNameSpace.
    self._$body.bind('touchend.myNameSpace').function (event) {
        self._$body.unbind('touchmove.myNameSpace');
    });

    return this;
},
```

PS: You might want to use a library like HammerJS (https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js) to make gestures work cross browser and also on non-touch devices.

Answer (score 1):

First I will suggest you to use Modernizr to detect touch

```
if (Modernizr.touch) {
    $("body").swipe({
        //Generic swipe handler for all directions
        swipe: function (event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {
         if(distance >= 100) //Check the units in px or unit
         {
            if (direction === "up") {
                   self.customScrollTo(nextStep);
            } else if (direction === "down") {
                   self.customScrollTo(prevStep);
            }
         }
       }
    });
}
```

I am just putting logic above. "self" is your object only.

for swipe event to work you have to include a jquery plugin https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin

Comment: Sniffing for touch is unreliable since nowadays devices can support both mouse and touch at the same time (Chromebooks and many W8 PC's) and some devices do support touch but do not have a touch device connected and thus result in a false positive.

Answer (score 0):

I think the event touchmove is firing multiple times, try to use touchend instead.

Regarding to: http://css-tricks.com/the-javascript-behind-touch-friendly-sliders/
I have tested your code with google chrome live javascript edit.
and it worked with the following modification in touchmove event.

```
setTimeout(function(){ self.customScrollTo(nextStep); }, 250);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Initialize touch event listener.
 *
 * @returns {Plugin}
 */

touch: function () {
    var self = this;
    var flag = false;
    this._$body.bind('touchstart', function (event) {
        var startEvent = event.originalEvent.touches[0];


        self._$body.bind('touchmove', function (event) {
            var moveEvent = event.originalEvent.touches[0];
            var diff = { x: startEvent.clientX - moveEvent.clientX, y: startEvent.clientY - moveEvent.clientY };
            var nextStep;

            if (((diff.y <= -100 || diff.y >= 100) && Math.abs(diff.y) > Math.abs(diff.x)) && flag == true) {

                nextStep = diff.y < 0 ? self._currentStep - 1 : self._currentStep + 1;
                self.customScrollTo(nextStep);
                startEvent = event.originalEvent.touches[0];  // Just added this line here.
            }
            event.preventDefault();

            return false;
        });

        return false;
    });

    return this;
},
```

I guess there is a simple edit required.
After you have exceeded the "diff" by 100 or -100 then just update the value of "startEvent" variable. Hence I have added the statement

```
  startEvent = event.originalEvent.touches[0];
```

So when the event for "self.customScrollTo(nextStep)" is triggered, the "startEvent" value is new value which is the current position of the touched point. And hence when again the touchmove event is called. It will again get a new set of values to calculate.
Please check this code and tell me if this works or not. Even if it is not right.